# Source setup not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I was trying to install ros jade on my ubuntu (VBox) and I followed [this](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu)
and couldn't really progress past step 2.

When I try sourcing the ubuntu server my terminal does not give me an error or anything, it just does nothing. Like this [source setup output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRLCD.png)

Anyone have any ideas why ?

Comment: @user535733 Wow, that makes me feel so stupid. And I don't just copy and paste random stuff xD. Thanks for pointing out the syntax mistake. Feel free to write that up as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you entered (perhaps due to copy-and-paste) seems to be missing a close quote (').

Simply type the close quote ('), and hit `ENTER`